# Match byte patterns 

Tags: java, byte

Say you are having a byte of pattern:

`byte b = 0x%1;`

How to tell when a byte does have certain values on the "2nd position" - in place of `%` ?
In this example 1, no matter what the 1st position holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mask bits to get the last 8 bits:

```
int last8bits = b & 0xF;
```

---

Edit: You should read up on [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

---

**Full example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte b = (byte) 0xA1;
    int last8bits = b & 0xF;

    if (last8bits == 0x01)
        System.out.println("\"matches\"");
}
```

Comment: thanks! I am really low at byte level operations :( Could you please also tell me how to get the first 8 bits ?

Comment: `if ((b & 0xF0) == 0x10) ...` or just left shift 8: `if ((b >> 8) & 0xF) == 0x1) ...` (updated answer with link to [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation))

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((0x0F & b) == 0x01) {
    // pattern matched
```